# Best/easiest way to make a 2D Chess board using Javascript/HTML5?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

I am building a web based chess game in Javascript. I'm using the HTML5 canvas to display the board by drawing rectangles.

I am trying to implement the move logic. So when a chess piece is clicked, and then they click on an empty block, I want to move it. However, it is quite tedious using the canvas. I need to do the following:

- Update my 2D grid of objects to reflect the change, I set the current
  square to undefined and set the new square to the object being moved
- clearRect(..) which I still haven't got to work
- Redraw the image at the new position

Is there a better way?

Also, how do I deal with the 'double click'. I currently using a boolean that holds if the piece was pressed, and if it was and they click on an empty square I call the move function. Are there any other ways of doing this? Additionally, are there any tools for making it seem like the chess piece is being dragged?

I appreciate any help. Thanks guys.

Comment: [chessboard.js](http://chessboardjs.com/)

Answer (score 4):

Over the years I've written a lot of chessboards for HTML. In the end the simplest approach I think is:

- Keep an array (either 1d or 2d, both have pros and cons) with just piece names (e.g. "wp"=white pawn, "bn"=black night, "--" empty). Nothing to be gained with an OO-approach or even a generic piece object.
- Use one single canvas for the board, drawing the pieces on them with `drawImage`.
- Write a function that just draws everything and call it when needed (don't bother erasing/drawing single pieces).
- For piece dragging empty the square and create a separate dragged `div` containing just the dragged piece (redrawing the full board during drag can be slow for low-end mobile devices).
- For dragging attach `move` and `up` handlers to the `document` and not to the canvas, so that you won't miss `up` events when the mouse is outside of the browser window.
- Start dragging on `mousedown` and attach events for `mousemove` and `mouseup`. This will work both on computers and on mobile phones without having to handle specific cases. Always call `preventDefault` and `stopPropagation`.
- Make full-page view with no overflow and handle resize yourself (you'll need to add some mobile-specific `meta`s to stop phones messing up with the page).

HTML can really do impressive things with just 2d canvas, as an example see [this 2d/3d chessboard](https://youtu.be/esFzFlY4PRs). One single file less than 300k (200k zipped).

Answer (score 1):

### Easiest you say?

Using [chessboard.js](http://chessboardjs.com/) *has* to be the easiest way and it is `2D`.

**HTML**

```
<div id="board1" style="width: 400px"></div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var board1 = ChessBoard('board1', 'start');
```

It has very good [documentation](http://chessboardjs.com/docs) and tons of different [examples](http://chessboardjs.com/examples#1000) (customization) and can be downloaded [here](http://chessboardjs.com/download).

Comment: I should have specified that I'd much prefer to make it myself. Thanks for the link though.

Answer (score 1):

**Learning by coding -- Good for you!**

Here are a few tips to get you started:

**A reusable structure for your game:**

- Create a JS object for each of your chess pieces and save those piece-objects in an array.

  ```
  // an example piece object
  var blackKing={
      player:'black',
      pieceType:'king',
      image:blackKingImageObject,
      currentSquare:['E','1'],
      isCaptured: false,
      // etc...
  }

  // a pieces-array
  var pieces=[];
  pieces.push(blackKing);
  ```
- Create a function that does all of these things:

  - clearRect the entire canvas,
  - redraw the chess board,
  - use the piece-array to redraw all the pieces onto the chessboard.

**About click vs double-click vs dragging:**

Yes, that's troublesome and requires special handling.

Many coders handle it this way:

- Listen for mousedown and save that timestamp and initial mouse position.
- If a mouseup plus another mousedown occurs quickly it's a double-click.
- If a mousemove of more than a few pixels occurs then it's the start of a drag.
- Otherwise, it's a single-click.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to spawn each piece via some factory/class/etc?

Comment: Sure, a function that accepts the piece properties and returns a piece-object would be handy.